# Java truststore updated on the fly. Is this kind of behaviour possible?

Tags: java

Today we had production issue for which we had to install ssl certificates for an application. So I'm trying to update ssl certificates  in my truststore which is already configured in jvm properties. But I've observed that without restart of jvm, I can see  applications deployed on the jvm have picked up certificates. Is this kind of behaviour possible??